# for loop using knockout js view.items()

Tags: javascript, for-loop, knockout.js

I am using the below code to iterated through the items list,

```
alert(view.items().length);
for(var i=0; i < view.items().length; i++){
      alert(view.items(i).productStatus);
}
```

I am getting an undefined error. Am i missing some thing??

Comment: what is return value of `view.items()` .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should access the array as view.items()[i].productStatus.
Assuming items is an observable array.

```
for(var i=0; i < view.items().length; i++){
      alert(view.items()[i].productStatus);
}
```